# v-show doesn't work as expected

Tags: javascript, vue.js

When the array shows[] changes after I click the button(I can see the shows[] changes in the Vue's chrome plugin), character 'a' is still on the page.'b' and 'c' never show up.

```js
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script>
    let vm = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {
        currentShow:0,
        shows:[true, false, false],
        },
        watch:{
            currentShow: function (val, old) {
                this.shows[old] = false;
                this.shows[val] = true
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

```html
<!-- Letter 'a', 'b', 'c' shows only when its corresponding shows[] is true-->
<div id="app">
    <p v-show="shows[0]">a</p>
    <p v-show="shows[1]">b</p>
    <p v-show="shows[2]">c</p>
    <button @click="currentShow=(currentShow+1)%3">next</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, currentShow changes as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a reactivity caveat. You could use `Vue.set()`:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>

<!-- Letter 'a', 'b', 'c' shows only when its corresponding shows[] is true-->
<div id="app">
    <p v-show="shows[0]">a</p>
    <p v-show="shows[1]">b</p>
    <p v-show="shows[2]">c</p>
    <button @click="currentShow=(currentShow+1)%3">next</button>
</div>

<script>
    let vm = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {
            currentShow: 0,
            shows:[true, false, false],
        },
        watch:{
            currentShow: function (val, old) {
                Vue.set(this.shows, old, false);
                Vue.set(this.shows, val, true);
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

Docs:

If you add or edit elements by index, you [have to call `Vue.set()`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats):

```
Vue.set(this.shows, old, false);
Vue.set(this.shows, val, true);
```

Or:

```
this.shows.splice(old, 1, false);
this.shows.splice(val, 1, true);
```

This enables Vue to adjust the reactivity to that element.

## Why?

Besides regular caveat problems, the docs have [a specific guidance on arrays](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Caveats):

> #### Caveats
>
> Due to limitations in JavaScript, Vue **cannot** detect the following
> changes to an array:
>
> 1. When you directly set an item with the index, e.g. `vm.items[indexOfItem] = newValue`
> 2. When you modify the length of the array, e.g. `vm.items.length = newLength`
>
> For example:
>
> ```
> var vm = new Vue({
>   data: {
>     items: ['a', 'b', 'c']
>   }
> })
> vm.items[1] = 'x' // is NOT reactive
> vm.items.length = 2 // is NOT reactive
> ```
>
> To overcome caveat 1, both of the following will accomplish the same
> as `vm.items[indexOfItem] = newValue`, but will also trigger state
> updates in the reactivity system:
>
> ```
> // Vue.set
> Vue.set(vm.items, indexOfItem, newValue)
>
> // Array.prototype.splice
> vm.items.splice(indexOfItem, 1, newValue)
> ```
>
> You can also use the [`vm.$set`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-set)
> instance method, which is an alias for the global `Vue.set`:
>
> ```
> vm.$set(vm.items, indexOfItem, newValue)
> ```
>
> To deal with caveat 2, you can use `splice`:
>
> ```
> vm.items.splice(newLength)
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Vue cannot watch on array elements if they are primitives (not objects typically). Vue updated is triggered by `push()`, `pop()` and other methods but it cannot know when you update a value inside. See the [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Mutation-Methods).

I found a specific solution for your example, where it can only be one selected item, feel free to adapt it.

```js
let vm = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
      currentShow: 0
    },
    methods: {
    
      showNext(){
        this.currentShow = (this.currentShow+1) % 3
      }
      
    }
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>

<!-- Letter 'a', 'b', 'c' shows only when its corresponding shows[] is true-->
<div id="app">
    <p v-show="currentShow==0">a</p>
    <p v-show="currentShow==1">b</p>
    <p v-show="currentShow==2">c</p>
    <button @click="showNext()">next</button>
</div>
```